# android.widget.Listview (inside RelativeLayout) does not get scroll after registering touch event

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, touch

**Listview scroll down/up Not working 
after registering touch event **

```
Public init()
{
myListView.Touch += myListView_Touch;
}


void myListView_Touch(object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Event.Action)
            {
     case MotionEventActions.Move:
            float x = e.Event.GetX();
            float y = e.Event.GetY();
            break;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**here**
     "MotionEventActions.Move" gets handled , it prevents further operation ,
when i force fully set to 
     e.Handled = false; , event executes further and it get scrolled.